# D3.js animate a circle along x, y coordinates

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I  would like to animate a circle along x,y coordinates. I want the circle to move along the provided x,y coordinates. So far my code is just drawing multiple circles for each x,y  point. The circles follow the x,y coordinates but all I want is one circle to move along the points. I have provided a sample of few datapoints. The dataset has thousands of x,y points.

```
//Sample data
var dataPoints = [
      { "x": 58.83, "y": 26.67 },
      { "x": 58.83, "y": 26.69 },
      { "x": 58.82, "y": 26.71 },
      { "x": 58.82, "y": 26.72 },
      { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.73 },
      { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.71 },
      { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.7 },
      { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.68 },
      { "x": 58.79, "y": 26.66 },
      { "x": 58.79, "y": 26.63 },
      { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.61 },
      { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.59 },
      { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.56 },
      { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.53 },
      { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.51 },
      { "x": 58.82, "y": 26.48 },
      { "x": 58.83, "y": 26.46 },
      { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.45 },
      { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.46 },
      { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.47 },
      { "x": 58.83, "y": 26.49 },
      { "x": 58.83, "y": 26.51 },
      { "x": 58.83, "y": 26.53 },
      { "x": 58.82, "y": 26.55 },
      { "x": 58.82, "y": 26.58 },
      { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.6 },
      { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.62 },
      { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.64 },
      { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.67 },
      { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.69 },
      { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.7 },
      { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.71 },
      { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.72 },
      { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.71 },
      { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.7 },
      { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.67 },
      { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.63 },
      { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.6 },
      { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.57 },
      { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.53 },
      { "x": 58.82, "y": 26.51 },
      { "x": 58.83, "y": 26.48 },
      { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.45 },
      { "x": 58.85, "y": 26.43 },
      { "x": 58.85, "y": 26.42 },
      { "x": 58.86, "y": 26.41 },
      { "x": 58.86, "y": 26.4 },
      { "x": 58.85, "y": 26.41 },
      { "x": 58.85, "y": 26.42 },
      { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.43 },
      { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.45 },
      { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.47 },
      { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.49 },
      { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.52 },
      { "x": 58.83, "y": 26.56 },
      { "x": 58.82, "y": 26.59 },
      { "x": 58.82, "y": 26.64 },
      { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.67 },
      { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.7 },
      { "x": 58.79, "y": 26.73 },
      { "x": 58.79, "y": 26.75 },
      { "x": 58.78, "y": 26.76 },
      { "x": 58.78, "y": 26.74 },
      { "x": 58.78, "y": 26.71 },
      { "x": 58.78, "y": 26.69 },
      { "x": 58.78, "y": 26.65 },
      { "x": 58.78, "y": 26.6 },
      { "x": 58.78, "y": 26.56 },
      { "x": 58.79, "y": 26.52 },
      { "x": 58.79, "y": 26.48 }
    ]
```

This is the part of the code that is drawing the circles in D3.

```
   var myCircle = this.svg.append('g');
  
 // Add circles 
   myCircle.selectAll("circle")
      .data(
        dataPoints
      )
      .enter()
      .append("circle")

      .attr("cx", function (d: { x: d3.NumberValue; }) {

        return x(d.x);
      })
      .attr("cy", function (d: { y: d3.NumberValue; }) {
        return y(d.y);
      })
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("opacity", .9)

      .style("fill", this.myColor)
      .transition()
      .delay(3000)
      .duration(3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example based on [one from Mike Bostock](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868). You can create a path and then use [attrTween](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_attrTween) to move the circle along the path.

```html
<!-- Updated example from https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868 -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script>
      // set up
      const margin = { top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10 };

      const width = 175 - margin.left - margin.right;
      const height = 175 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      const svg = d3.select('#chart')
        .append('svg')
          .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

      const g = svg.append('g')
          .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

      // data
      const dataPoints = [
        { "x": 58.83, "y": 26.67 },
        { "x": 58.83, "y": 26.69 },
        { "x": 58.82, "y": 26.71 },
        { "x": 58.82, "y": 26.72 },
        { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.73 },
        { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.71 },
        { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.7 },
        { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.68 },
        { "x": 58.79, "y": 26.66 },
        { "x": 58.79, "y": 26.63 },
        { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.61 },
        { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.59 },
        { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.56 },
        { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.53 },
        { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.51 },
        { "x": 58.82, "y": 26.48 },
        { "x": 58.83, "y": 26.46 },
        { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.45 },
        { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.46 },
        { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.47 },
        { "x": 58.83, "y": 26.49 },
        { "x": 58.83, "y": 26.51 },
        { "x": 58.83, "y": 26.53 },
        { "x": 58.82, "y": 26.55 },
        { "x": 58.82, "y": 26.58 },
        { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.6 },
        { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.62 },
        { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.64 },
        { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.67 },
        { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.69 },
        { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.7 },
        { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.71 },
        { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.72 },
        { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.71 },
        { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.7 },
        { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.67 },
        { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.63 },
        { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.6 },
        { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.57 },
        { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.53 },
        { "x": 58.82, "y": 26.51 },
        { "x": 58.83, "y": 26.48 },
        { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.45 },
        { "x": 58.85, "y": 26.43 },
        { "x": 58.85, "y": 26.42 },
        { "x": 58.86, "y": 26.41 },
        { "x": 58.86, "y": 26.4 },
        { "x": 58.85, "y": 26.41 },
        { "x": 58.85, "y": 26.42 },
        { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.43 },
        { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.45 },
        { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.47 },
        { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.49 },
        { "x": 58.84, "y": 26.52 },
        { "x": 58.83, "y": 26.56 },
        { "x": 58.82, "y": 26.59 },
        { "x": 58.82, "y": 26.64 },
        { "x": 58.81, "y": 26.67 },
        { "x": 58.8, "y": 26.7 },
        { "x": 58.79, "y": 26.73 },
        { "x": 58.79, "y": 26.75 },
        { "x": 58.78, "y": 26.76 },
        { "x": 58.78, "y": 26.74 },
        { "x": 58.78, "y": 26.71 },
        { "x": 58.78, "y": 26.69 },
        { "x": 58.78, "y": 26.65 },
        { "x": 58.78, "y": 26.6 },
        { "x": 58.78, "y": 26.56 },
        { "x": 58.79, "y": 26.52 },
        { "x": 58.79, "y": 26.48 }
      ];

      // scales
      const x = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain(d3.extent(dataPoints, d => d.x))
          .range([0, width]);

      const y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain(d3.extent(dataPoints, d => d.y))
          .range([height, 0]);

      // line generator
      const line = d3.line()
          .x(d => x(d.x))
          .y(d => y(d.y));

      // add path
      const path = g.append('path')
          .attr('d', line(dataPoints))
          .attr('stroke', 'none')
          .attr('fill', 'none');

      // draw circle at initial location
      const circle = g.append('circle')
          .attr('fill', 'red')
          .attr('r', 5)
          .attr('transform', `translate(${x(dataPoints[0].x)},${y(dataPoints[0].y)})`);

      // animate
      circle.transition()
          .ease(d3.easeLinear)
          .duration(5000)
          .attrTween('transform', translateAlong(path.node()));

      // https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868
      function translateAlong(path) {
        const length = path.getTotalLength();
        return function() {
          return function(t) {
            const {x, y} = path.getPointAtLength(t * length);
            return `translate(${x},${y})`;
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```